# OpenOffice doesn't work

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

I installed OpenOffice on 12.04, and set it as the default utility for spreadsheets, but it doesn't run at all.

While trying to troubleshoot, I read that it is not recommended to install it alongside LibreOffice. I am about to uninstall OpenOffice because I don't know how to get it working, and LibreOffice is opening my spreadsheet just fine.

But just out of curiosity, I also read that I should try deleting `.openoffice.org` folder; but from where? I don't see it under `/usr/lib`, nor under my `/home`.

Comment: OP remove [OO.o](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184604/openoffice-doesnt-work#comment230044_184605)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use **Openoffice** then you have to remove **Libreoffice** from your system. Open a terminal and then type

`sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*`

It will remove **LibreOffice** completely. Then download the latest version of **OpenOffice** from [here](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/openofficeorg.mirror/stable/3.4.1/Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz).
Extract it in your desktop. Then open a terminal and type

`cd ~/Desktop`

`cd en-US`

`cd DEBS`

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

After finished instaling type

`cd desktop-integration`

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Now it is ready to go. It set default for your office files.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

openoffice folder is locate under `/home/YOUR USERNAME/.openoffice`

its hidden press `CTRL`-`H` to view hidden Folders!

---

When you have a file and or folder (`ubuntu`/`ubuntu.txt`) that you want hidden

All you have to do is start the name with a `.` it should look like so.

folder `.ubuntu` file `.ubuntu.txt` refresh the page `F5` and your file/folder is hidden

Comment: Tried ctrl-h, also tried "ls -al $HOME | grep openof" but can't see .openoffi* file/folder. No wonder it is not working, but it seemed to install just fine. And I can even see its icons (OpenOffice.org.3.4 and OpenOffice.org.3.4.calc etc).

Comment: ? lets start from scratch run this 'sudo apt-get remove openoffice*'

Comment: hello blade19899 - I am sorry but there just isn't enough time and incentive for me to try OpenOffice again when LibreOffice is working and I have read enough good things about it during the last hour. That word was unknown to me until today. While tryint to install OpenOffice, at 'sudo apt-get update' step, my laptop once hanged and I had to reboot it by pressing power key. Next time that cmd worked, then OpenOffice was installed smoothly but took a looong time, and then it didn't work. Very well, I will just stick with LibreOffice.

Comment: OK. So you removed open office completely?

Comment: Yes, I removed it completely. While OpenOffice would rather that you installed it anyway and then perhaps deleted LibreOffice, neutral help-sites should mention first IMO that the two do not co-exist as of Sep-2012.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble getting it to work. I could see the file in the Opt/directory but it would not work. I tried two different downloads, nothing worked until I used the sudo remove command mentioned earlier. and repeated the dpkg commands as mentioned. I then opened my search tab and typed in open office, and found it there and opened the file. Once it opened I right clicked and hit the lock to launcher. Thank you Kaktarua for your post...

Comment: This does not seem to be a complete answer and probably should only be a comment. If you want to thank someone here, please just vote up the answer.