# error while installing openoffice

Tags: apt

I was installing openoffice using these commands

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

Now after downloading some 20MB my internet connection interrupted when again it tried to install it says as follows

```
 Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/ precise/main openoffice amd64 3.4~precise
 Connection failed
 Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openoffice/openoffice_3.4~precise_amd64.deb  Connection failed
 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

how to solve these errors ?

Comment: Did you try <sudo apt-get --fix-missing install> from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, this should fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install openoffice --fix-missing
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **LibreOffice** to successfully use **OpenOffice**, and *vice versa*.

One is a *fork* (variation) of the other, and they don't *play well* together.

---

See answer for: [OpenOffice doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184604/openoffice-doesnt-work)