# Errors when installing Open Office

Tags: software-installation

I followed the first set of instructions on this page to install Open Office:

- [How do I install OpenOffice instead of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-to-install-open-office)

However, the last step which says to change the CHMOD of a folder, I got an error saying that the directory does not exist.

Open Office now appears in my Ubuntu start menu, but clicking on it does nothing. I tried a reboot.

Below is what I could copy from my terminal.

I am running the latest Ubuntu. I have not uninstalled Libreoffice as suggested somewhere. The reason is that in the Ubuntu software centre, Libre office appears to be made up of several components and I don't know which ones to remove (or all maybe?). They are Libreoffice Draw, Math, Writer, Calc.

```
After this operation, 480 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe openjdk-6-jre-lib all 6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1 [6,135 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/ quantal/main openoffice amd64 3.4~oneiric [321 MB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main ca-certificates-java all 20120721 [13.2 kB]
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main tzdata-java all 2012e-0ubuntu2 [140 kB]
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main java-common all 0.43ubuntu3 [61.7 kB]
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe openjdk-6-jre-headless amd64 6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1 [25.4 MB]
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libgif4 amd64 4.1.6-9.1ubuntu1 [31.3 kB]
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe openjdk-6-jre amd64 6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1 [234 kB]
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libatk-wrapper-java all 0.30.4-0ubuntu4 [29.8 kB]
Get:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libatk-wrapper-java-jni amd64 0.30.4-0ubuntu4 [31.1 kB]
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main xorg-sgml-doctools all 1:1.10-1 [12.0 kB]
Get:12 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main x11proto-core-dev all 7.0.23-1 [744 kB]
Get:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libice-dev amd64 2:1.0.8-2 [57.6 kB]
Get:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libpthread-stubs0 amd64 0.3-3 [3,258 B]
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libpthread-stubs0-dev amd64 0.3-3 [2,866 B]
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libsm-dev amd64 2:1.2.1-2 [19.9 kB]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxau-dev amd64 1:1.0.7-1 [10.2 kB]
Get:18 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxdmcp-dev amd64 1:1.1.1-1 [26.9 kB]
Get:19 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main x11proto-input-dev all 2.2-1 [133 kB]
Get:20 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main x11proto-kb-dev all 1.0.6-2 [269 kB]
Get:21 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main xtrans-dev all 1.2.7-1 [84.3 kB]
Get:22 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxcb1-dev amd64 1.8.1-1ubuntu1 [82.6 kB]
Get:23 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libx11-dev amd64 2:1.5.0-1 [912 kB]
Get:24 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libx11-doc all 2:1.5.0-1 [2,460 kB]
Get:25 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxt-dev amd64 1:1.1.3-1 [492 kB]
Get:26 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main ttf-dejavu-extra all 2.33-2ubuntu1 [3,420 kB]
Get:27 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe icedtea-6-jre-cacao amd64 6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1 [417 kB]
Get:28 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe icedtea-6-jre-jamvm amd64 6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1 [581 kB]
Get:29 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main icedtea-netx-common all 1.3-1ubuntu1.1 [617 kB]
Get:30 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main icedtea-netx amd64 1.3-1ubuntu1.1 [16.2 kB]
Get:31 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/universe openjdk-6-jdk amd64 6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1 [11.1 MB]
Fetched 374 MB in 9min 18s (671 kB/s)                                          
Extract templates from packages: 100%
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-6-jre-lib.
(Reading database ... 143191 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openjdk-6-jre-lib (from .../openjdk-6-jre-lib_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates-java.
Unpacking ca-certificates-java (from .../ca-certificates-java_20120721_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tzdata-java.
Unpacking tzdata-java (from .../tzdata-java_2012e-0ubuntu2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package java-common.
Unpacking java-common (from .../java-common_0.43ubuntu3_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64.
Unpacking openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64 (from .../openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgif4:amd64.
Unpacking libgif4:amd64 (from .../libgif4_4.1.6-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-6-jre:amd64.
Unpacking openjdk-6-jre:amd64 (from .../openjdk-6-jre_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatk-wrapper-java.
Unpacking libatk-wrapper-java (from .../libatk-wrapper-java_0.30.4-0ubuntu4_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64.
Unpacking libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64 (from .../libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.30.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xorg-sgml-doctools.
Unpacking xorg-sgml-doctools (from .../xorg-sgml-doctools_1%3a1.10-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-core-dev.
Unpacking x11proto-core-dev (from .../x11proto-core-dev_7.0.23-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libice-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libice-dev:amd64 (from .../libice-dev_2%3a1.0.8-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpthread-stubs0:amd64.
Unpacking libpthread-stubs0:amd64 (from .../libpthread-stubs0_0.3-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (from .../libpthread-stubs0-dev_0.3-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsm-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libsm-dev:amd64 (from .../libsm-dev_2%3a1.2.1-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxau-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libxau-dev:amd64 (from .../libxau-dev_1%3a1.0.7-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libxdmcp-dev:amd64 (from .../libxdmcp-dev_1%3a1.1.1-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-input-dev.
Unpacking x11proto-input-dev (from .../x11proto-input-dev_2.2-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-kb-dev.
Unpacking x11proto-kb-dev (from .../x11proto-kb-dev_1.0.6-2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xtrans-dev.
Unpacking xtrans-dev (from .../xtrans-dev_1.2.7-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libxcb1-dev:amd64 (from .../libxcb1-dev_1.8.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libx11-dev:amd64 (from .../libx11-dev_2%3a1.5.0-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-doc.
Unpacking libx11-doc (from .../libx11-doc_2%3a1.5.0-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxt-dev:amd64.
Unpacking libxt-dev:amd64 (from .../libxt-dev_1%3a1.1.3-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ttf-dejavu-extra.
Unpacking ttf-dejavu-extra (from .../ttf-dejavu-extra_2.33-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64.
Unpacking icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64 (from .../icedtea-6-jre-cacao_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64.
Unpacking icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64 (from .../icedtea-6-jre-jamvm_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-netx-common.
Unpacking icedtea-netx-common (from .../icedtea-netx-common_1.3-1ubuntu1.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-netx:amd64.
Unpacking icedtea-netx:amd64 (from .../icedtea-netx_1.3-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-6-jdk:amd64.
Unpacking openjdk-6-jdk:amd64 (from .../openjdk-6-jdk_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openoffice.
Unpacking openoffice (from .../openoffice_3.4~oneiric_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 2 added doc-base files...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Setting up tzdata-java (2012e-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up java-common (0.43ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libgif4:amd64 (4.1.6-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xorg-sgml-doctools (1:1.10-1) ...
Setting up x11proto-core-dev (7.0.23-1) ...
Setting up libice-dev:amd64 (2:1.0.8-2) ...
Setting up libpthread-stubs0:amd64 (0.3-3) ...
Setting up libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (0.3-3) ...
Setting up libsm-dev:amd64 (2:1.2.1-2) ...
Setting up libxau-dev:amd64 (1:1.0.7-1) ...
Setting up libxdmcp-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.1-1) ...
Setting up x11proto-input-dev (2.2-1) ...
Setting up x11proto-kb-dev (1.0.6-2) ...
Setting up xtrans-dev (1.2.7-1) ...
Setting up libxcb1-dev:amd64 (1.8.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libx11-dev:amd64 (2:1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up libx11-doc (2:1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up libxt-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.3-1) ...
Setting up ttf-dejavu-extra (2.33-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up icedtea-netx-common (1.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-lib (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) ...
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64 (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd to provide /usr/bin/orbd (orbd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/servertool to provide /usr/bin/servertool (servertool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/tnameserv to provide /usr/bin/tnameserv (tnameserv) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20120721) ...
Adding debian:Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Comodo_Trusted_Services_root.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem
Adding debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:AddTrust_Low-Value_Services_Root.pem
Adding debian:Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:ComSign_Secured_CA.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_2_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:Certum_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:AddTrust_External_Root.pem
Adding debian:Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Visa_eCommerce_Root.pem
Adding debian:Digital_Signature_Trust_Co._Global_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:AC_Raíz_Certicámara_S.A..pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem
Adding debian:Taiwan_GRCA.pem
Adding debian:Camerfirma_Chambers_of_Commerce_Root.pem
Adding debian:Juur-SK.pem
Adding debian:Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
Adding debian:AddTrust_Qualified_Certificates_Root.pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Qualified_=Class_QA=_Root.pem
Adding debian:TC_TrustCenter_Class_2_CA_II.pem
Adding debian:DST_ACES_CA_X6.pem
Adding debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Universal_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:ACEDICOM_Root.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_EV_RootCA1.pem
Adding debian:America_Online_Root_Certification_Authority_2.pem
Adding debian:TC_TrustCenter_Universal_CA_I.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Platinum_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem
Adding debian:SecureSign_RootCA11.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Global_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Buypass_Class_3_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem
Adding debian:UbuntuOne-Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:Equifax_Secure_eBusiness_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
Adding debian:TC_TrustCenter_Universal_CA_III.pem
Adding debian:ca.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Express_=Class_C=_Root.pem
Adding debian:VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.pem
Adding debian:Firmaprofesional_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Comodo_Secure_Services_root.pem
Adding debian:cacert.org.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:RSA_Security_2048_v3.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Cybertrust_Global_Root.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:TDC_OCES_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:A-Trust-nQual-03.pem
Adding debian:Equifax_Secure_CA.pem
Adding debian:Digital_Signature_Trust_Co._Global_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:ApplicationCA_-_Japanese_Government.pem
Adding debian:Swisscom_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_2_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Camerfirma_Global_Chambersign_Root.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem
Adding debian:ComSign_CA.pem
Adding debian:AddTrust_Public_Services_Root.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:UTN_DATACorp_SGC_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:CA_Disig.pem
Adding debian:E-Guven_Kok_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Saglayicisi.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem
Adding debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.pem
Adding debian:ValiCert_Class_1_VA.pem
Adding debian:Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:spi-ca-2003.pem
Adding debian:America_Online_Root_Certification_Authority_1.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
Adding debian:Sonera_Class_1_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_2_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:Certplus_Class_2_Primary_CA.pem
Adding debian:TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_2.pem
Adding debian:Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
Adding debian:StartCom_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem
Adding debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2011.pem
Adding debian:Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı.pem
Adding debian:TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_1.pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Business_=Class_B=_Root.pem
Adding debian:Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem
Adding debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem
Adding debian:IGC_A.pem
Adding debian:TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:S-TRUST_Authentication_and_Encryption_Root_CA_2005_PN.pem
Adding debian:VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_1_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Root_CA_Generalitat_Valenciana.pem
Adding debian:UTN_USERFirst_Email_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
Adding debian:Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:Certinomis_-_Autorité_Racine.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:TDC_Internet_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:UbuntuOne-ValiCert_Class_2_VA.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
Adding debian:spi-cacert-2008.pem
Adding debian:Izenpe.com.pem
Adding debian:EC-ACC.pem
Adding debian:Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:CNNIC_ROOT.pem
Adding debian:NetLock_Notary_=Class_A=_Root.pem
Adding debian:Equifax_Secure_eBusiness_CA_2.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:Secure_Global_CA.pem
Adding debian:UbuntuOne-Go_Daddy_CA.pem
Adding debian:GeoTrust_Universal_CA.pem
Adding debian:Wells_Fargo_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Thawte_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:WellsSecure_Public_Root_Certificate_Authority.pem
Adding debian:TC_TrustCenter_Class_3_CA_II.pem
Adding debian:COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Equifax_Secure_Global_eBusiness_CA.pem
Adding debian:Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.pem
Adding debian:TÜBİTAK_UEKAE_Kök_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_-_Sürüm_3.pem
Adding debian:Verisign_Class_4_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem
Adding debian:certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem
Adding debian:RSA_Root_Certificate_1.pem
Adding debian:ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Adding debian:Entrust.net_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Adding debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GA_CA.pem
Adding debian:Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Certigna.pem
Adding debian:AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
Adding debian:ValiCert_Class_2_VA.pem
Adding debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:SecureTrust_CA.pem
done.
Setting up openjdk-6-jre:amd64 (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/policytool to provide /usr/bin/policytool (policytool) in auto mode
Setting up libatk-wrapper-java (0.30.4-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64 (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) ...
Setting up icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64 (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) ...
Setting up icedtea-netx:amd64 (1.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws to provide /usr/bin/javaws (javaws) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings to provide /usr/bin/itweb-settings (itweb-settings) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws to provide /usr/bin/javaws (javaws) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings to provide /usr/bin/itweb-settings (itweb-settings) in auto mode
Setting up openjdk-6-jdk:amd64 (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.10.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer to provide /usr/bin/appletviewer (appletviewer) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/extcheck to provide /usr/bin/extcheck (extcheck) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/idlj to provide /usr/bin/idlj (idlj) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar to provide /usr/bin/jar (jar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner to provide /usr/bin/jarsigner (jarsigner) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc to provide /usr/bin/javadoc (javadoc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah to provide /usr/bin/javah (javah) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap to provide /usr/bin/javap (javap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole to provide /usr/bin/jconsole (jconsole) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdb to provide /usr/bin/jdb (jdb) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jhat to provide /usr/bin/jhat (jhat) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jinfo to provide /usr/bin/jinfo (jinfo) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jmap to provide /usr/bin/jmap (jmap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps to provide /usr/bin/jps (jps) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jrunscript to provide /usr/bin/jrunscript (jrunscript) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jsadebugd to provide /usr/bin/jsadebugd (jsadebugd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstack to provide /usr/bin/jstack (jstack) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat to provide /usr/bin/jstat (jstat) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstatd to provide /usr/bin/jstatd (jstatd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/native2ascii to provide /usr/bin/native2ascii (native2ascii) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmic to provide /usr/bin/rmic (rmic) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/schemagen to provide /usr/bin/schemagen (schemagen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/serialver to provide /usr/bin/serialver (serialver) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsgen to provide /usr/bin/wsgen (wsgen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsimport to provide /usr/bin/wsimport (wsimport) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/xjc to provide /usr/bin/xjc (xjc) in auto mode
Setting up openoffice (3.4~oneiric) ...
Setting up libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64 (0.30.4-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
philip@X301-2:~$ sudo apt-get install libxrandr2:i386 libxinerama1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.7-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  gcc-4.7-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386
  libxrender1:i386
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,936 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main gcc-4.7-base i386 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 [15.5 kB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libc6 i386 2.15-0ubuntu20 [3,940 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libgcc1 i386 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 [53.5 kB]
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxau6 i386 1:1.0.7-1 [8,582 B]
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxdmcp6 i386 1:1.1.1-1 [13.1 kB]
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxcb1 i386 1.8.1-1ubuntu1 [48.7 kB]
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libx11-6 i386 2:1.5.0-1 [776 kB]
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxext6 i386 2:1.3.1-2 [33.9 kB]
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxinerama1 i386 2:1.1.2-1 [8,118 B]
Get:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxrender1 i386 1:0.9.7-1 [20.1 kB]
Get:11 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main libxrandr2 i386 2:1.4.0-1 [18.8 kB]
Fetched 4,936 kB in 30s (161 kB/s)                                             
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-4.7-base:i386.
(Reading database ... 146005 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gcc-4.7-base:i386 (from .../gcc-4.7-base_4.7.2-2ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6:i386.
Unpacking libc6:i386 (from .../libc6_2.15-0ubuntu20_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc1:i386.
Unpacking libgcc1:i386 (from .../libgcc1_1%3a4.7.2-2ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxau6:i386.
Unpacking libxau6:i386 (from .../libxau6_1%3a1.0.7-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp6:i386.
Unpacking libxdmcp6:i386 (from .../libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.1-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1:i386.
Unpacking libxcb1:i386 (from .../libxcb1_1.8.1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-6:i386.
Unpacking libx11-6:i386 (from .../libx11-6_2%3a1.5.0-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxext6:i386.
Unpacking libxext6:i386 (from .../libxext6_2%3a1.3.1-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxinerama1:i386.
Unpacking libxinerama1:i386 (from .../libxinerama1_2%3a1.1.2-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxrender1:i386.
Unpacking libxrender1:i386 (from .../libxrender1_1%3a0.9.7-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxrandr2:i386.
Unpacking libxrandr2:i386 (from .../libxrandr2_2%3a1.4.0-1_i386.deb) ...
Setting up gcc-4.7-base:i386 (4.7.2-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libc6:i386 (2.15-0ubuntu20) ...
Setting up libgcc1:i386 (1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libxau6:i386 (1:1.0.7-1) ...
Setting up libxdmcp6:i386 (1:1.1.1-1) ...
Setting up libxcb1:i386 (1.8.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libx11-6:i386 (2:1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.1-2) ...
Setting up libxinerama1:i386 (2:1.1.2-1) ...
Setting up libxrender1:i386 (1:0.9.7-1) ...
Setting up libxrandr2:i386 (2:1.4.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
$ sudo chmod a+rx /opt/openoffice.org3/share/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages
chmod: cannot access `/opt/openoffice.org3/share/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You will NEED to remove LibreOffice for this.

`sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-core`

You may have to remove and reinstall Apache OpenOffice as well at this point; not too sure about that.  But the two packages definitely conflict.

Comment: Better would be: **sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice***

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Open Office. The differences between LibreOffice and Open Office are minimal to say the least and given that the dynamic of the community is now with LibreOffice which comes nicely pre-installed in Ubuntu, I wouldn't waste your time with OpenOffice.

Oracle decided after acquiring Sun that it was not interested in maintaining it and offloaded it to the Apache Foundation. Meanwhile many of the developers started LibreOffice as a fork of OpenOffice. Some developers do nevertheless continue to work on OpenOffice and I believe there was a new release not so long ago but as I said the differences between the two are negligible and the dynamic is clearly with LibreOffice these days.

Regarding uninstalling LibreOffice, I think you'll need to uninstall the packages separately since the meta-package is not installed by default.

Then I'd remove any OpenOffice packages - use synaptic - and start again using the method you were given.

However, once again I cannot recommend to go to all that fuss for a near identical suite of apps to what you have comfortably installed already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **LibreOffice** to successfully use **OpenOffice**, and *vice versa*.

One is a *fork* (variation) of the other, and they don't *play well* together.

---

See answer for: [OpenOffice doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184604/openoffice-doesnt-work)